# How to write a program that finds the greatest and smallest fractions?

Tags: c#

How do I write a program that finds the greatest and smallest fractions in a List ?

```
Console.WriteLine("How many fractions to comapre?");
        string nic = Console.ReadLine();
        int amount = int.Parse(nic);
        double min = 0; double max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter fraction to compare. WRITE AS IMPROPER FRCATION");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] each = str.Split('/');
            List<double> eachDoub = new List<double> { };
            foreach (string hit in each)
            {
                eachDoub.Add(double.Parse(hit));
            }
            List<double> finals = new List<double> { };
            foreach (double hit in eachDoub)
            {
                finals.Add(eachDoub[0] / eachDoub[1]);
            }
            max = finals.Max();
            min = finals.Min();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The maximum is {0} and the minimum is {1}.", max, min);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Input:
   How many fractions to comapre? 3
   Enter the fraction
   4/1
   Enter the fraction
   3/1

When I run this program it does not work correctly, it will only print the last value entered for both the min and the max.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be, what is the output? "It dosen't work" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: @EdwardKarak - I edited the question to show you what I meant by there not being a question.  Now there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move this line

```
 List<double> finals = new List<double> { };
```

out of the loop.

Why?  Because when you have it in the loop it does not keep track of all the values, it "resets" on each interrelation

Answer (score 2):

You just need to declare the finals list outside the `for` and also do the calculations outside too, for not calling the `Max()` and `Min()` methods three times when only one is necessary. In this case there are only 3 iterations, and the difference won't be significative, but as a good coding practice you should calculate those values outside the loop.

```
    Console.WriteLine("How many fractions to comapre?");
    string nic = Console.ReadLine();
    int amount = int.Parse(nic);
    double min = 0; double max = 0;
    List<double> finals = new List<double> { };

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter fraction to compare. WRITE AS IMPROPER FRCATION");
        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] each = str.Split('/');
        List<double> eachDoub = new List<double> { };
        foreach (string hit in each)
        {
            eachDoub.Add(double.Parse(hit));
        }

        foreach (double hit in eachDoub)
        {
            finals.Add(eachDoub[0] / eachDoub[1]);
        }
    }
    max = finals.Max();
    min = finals.Min();

    Console.WriteLine("The maximum is {0} and the minimum is {1}.", max, min);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Beat you by 20 secs :)  Also, it makes sense to put min and max outside the loop, but it is not required.

Comment: I think you would put it outside the loop in your own code and not inside the loop, am I right? :)

Answer (score 1):

This loop looks wrong -- the iteration variable is never used.

```
    foreach (double hit in eachDoub)
    {
        finals.Add(eachDoub[0] / eachDoub[1]);
    }
```